# Optional argument with a mandatory keyword

Tags: python

Is it possible to have an optional argument for a function, but make the use of a keyword necessary if it is to be declared in the function call?

For example,

```
def f(arg1, *otherargs, useme2declare):
    ....
```

requires a mandatory first argument, followed by some unspecified number of position and optional arguments (with optional keywords), but while `useme2declare` requires the keyword to be used in call, it is also a mandatory argument. How can I make it optional in a call? Putting it before `*otherargs` makes the keyword optional too.

EDIT: Please read my question carefully. I want to make the use of a keyword MANDATORY for `useme2declare` every time the function is called, and at the same time have entry of `useme2declare` optional.

Comment: Use a default value for the  optional argument?

Comment: @MSeifert Perhaps I didn't make my question clear; I've edited it to better reflect what I want my function to do.

Comment: Could you add an example how you want to call the function?

Comment: @MSeifert Suppose we have `def f(a,b=None): ...`; while `b` is certainly optional, I only want calls of the kind `f(1)`, `f(a=1,b=2)` and `f(1,b=2)` to be accepted. So `f(1,2)` should NOT work, nor should `f(a=1,2)`.

Comment: Can have a look at [PEP 570 -- Python Positional-Only Parameters | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#positional-only-parameters)

Comment: @LiuXiMin That is a very useful link; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the argument `useme2declare` *keyword-only* with `*` in the signature after all positional args, and use a default value for the base case:

```
def f(arg1, otherarg1, otherarg2, *, useme2declare=None):
```

Here is an example:

```
In [981]: def spam(*, egg=5): 
     ...:     return egg 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [982]: spam(100)                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-982-8ddebef6cd4e> in <module>
----> 1 spam(100)

TypeError: spam() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

In [983]: spam(egg=100)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[983]: 100
```

---

Note that, you can't use variable length positional arguments (e.g. `*args`) when using this.

But you're free to use variable length keyword arguments if you want:

```
def f(arg1, *, useme2declare=None, **kwargs):
```

Comment: The second `*` in the first example is not necessary. `def f(arg1, *otherargs, useme2declare=None):` is already sufficient. Any args following any `*` are automatically keywords

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration. It certainly does make it optional. Try running it.